# Iterating generically over either a map or a vector of 2-tuples

Tags: iterator, rust, traits

Because of [reasons](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38856), I want to define a generic function that can iterate over key-value pairs expressed either as a mapping, or as a vector of 2-tuples (or anything else that satisfies `IntoIterator<Item=(K, V)>`, where `K` and `V` are stringy).  Concretely, I want this to work:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let vc = vec![
        ("a", "foo"),
        ("b", "bar"),
        ("c", "baz")
    ];
    operate(&vc);

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("d", "blurf");
    map.insert("e", "quux");
    map.insert("f", "xyzzy");
    operate(&map);
}
```

I've got a definition of `operate` that works for the HashMap, but not for the vector:

```
fn operate<I, K, V>(x: I)
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=(K, V)>,
          K: AsRef<str>, V: AsRef<str>
{
    for (ref k, ref v) in x {
        println!("{}: {}", k.as_ref(), v.as_ref());
    }
}
```

The error message I get is

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&std::vec::Vec<(&str, &str)> as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == (_, _)`
  --> test.rs:18:5
   |
18 |     operate(&vc);
   |     ^^^^^^^ expected reference, found tuple
   |
   = note: expected type `&(&str, &str)`
   = note:    found type `(_, _)`
   = note: required by `operate`
```

and I don't understand it at all.  For one thing, it seems like it's backwards, and for another, why am I only getting an error for the `Vec` and not the `HashMap`?

Answer (score 7):

The function provided by [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) consumes self.

```
fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter
```

In order to allow the use of `IntoIterator` without consuming the collection, both [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) and [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) have implementations of `IntoIterator` for `&'a Vec<T>` and `&'a HashMap<K,V,S>`, respectively. However, they are not quite the same.

For the hash map, each `Item` is a `(&K, &V)`, which does not impose a problem because the code effectively assumes the items as 2-sized tuples of keys and values that coerce to `&str`. And `&&str` does indeed coerce to `&str`.
For the vector, each `Item` is a `&T` (thus `&(K, V)` in this case), but because the function is expecting `(K, V)` as the iterating item, it is currently unable to deal with items of `&(K, V)`.

As it is, the function works if you move the vector, which yields an `IntoIterator` where `Item = (K, V)`:

```
let vc = vec![
    ("a", "foo"),
    ("b", "bar"),
    ("c", "baz")
];
operate(vc);
```

But what if we want it to work for both collections without consuming any of them? Well, I just devised two solutions.

#### #1

This one involves hiding the tuple behind a new trait:

```
/// for stuff that can be turned into a pair of references
trait AsRefPair<K, V> {
    fn as_ref_pair(&self) -> (&K, &V);
}
```

Implementing it for for `&(K,V)` and `(&K,&V)`:

```
impl<'a, K, V> AsRefPair<K, V> for (&'a K, &'a V) {
    fn as_ref_pair(&self) -> (&K, &V) {
        (self.0, self.1)
    }
}

impl<'a, K, V> AsRefPair<K, V> for &'a (K, V) {
    fn as_ref_pair(&self) -> (&K, &V) {
        (&self.0, &self.1)
    }
}
```

And now this function works:

```
fn operate<I, T, K, V>(x: I)
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=T>,
          T: AsRefPair<K, V>,
          K: AsRef<str>, V: AsRef<str>
{
    for p in x {
        let (ref k, ref v) = p.as_ref_pair();
        println!("{}: {}", k.as_ref(), v.as_ref());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e2ae034a32e9fb18644cf2785fbe22f3&version=stable&backtrace=0). It might sound a bit crazy at first, but...!

#### #2

In this one, just stop working with tuples... and start working with key-values!

```
trait KeyValue<K, V> {
    fn key_value(&self) -> (&K, &V) {
        (self.key(), self.value())
    }

    fn key(&self) -> &K;
    fn value(&self) -> &V;
}

impl<K, V> KeyValue<K, V> for (K, V) {
    fn key(&self) -> &K {
        &self.0
    }
    fn value(&self) -> &V {
        &self.1
    }
}

impl<'a, K, V> KeyValue<K, V> for &'a (K, V) {
    fn key(&self) -> &K {
        &self.0
    }
    fn value(&self) -> &V {
        &self.1
    }
}

fn operate<I, T, K, V>(x: I)
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=T>,
          T: KeyValue<K, V>,
          K: AsRef<str>, V: AsRef<str>
{
    for p in x {
        let (ref k, ref v) = p.key_value();
        println!("{}: {}", k.as_ref(), v.as_ref());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4b5530a5b5428c1e78bed9121203cbfc&version=stable&backtrace=0). I find this one a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: It's required in context (see the hyperlink in the question) that `operate` not consume its argument.  Any other options?  Some way to write the match pattern in the `for` so it works either way, for instance?

Comment: I was working on a solution, hang in there! :) Done!

Answer (score 2):

If you pass to the function `operate()` an iterator instead of a reference to vector, you can use `Iterator` adaptors to convert `Iterator::Item` to what you need:

```
operate(vc.iter().map(|&(ref a, ref b)| (a, b)));
```

Comment: Indeed, using iterators is probably the most idiomatic way of doing this as it gives a lot more flexibility (also allows filtering the input, for example).

Comment: I believe `Iterator` implements `IntoIterator` trivially, so taking `IntoIterator` seems more general.